# Список диалогов sql запрос

Tags: php, sql

Нужно составить список диалогов между пользователями наподобии вконтакте. Имеется две таблицы для сообщений в диалоге межу пользователем использую такой запрос `"SELECT * FROM inbox WHERE user='$login' AND author='$sobesednik' UNION ALL SELECT * FROM outbox WHERE user='$sobesednik' AND author='$login' ORDER BY time"` не будет ли конфликтов между таблицами? название полей в таблицах одинаковые если что можно переименовать название полей на inbox_user, inbox_author и outbox _user, outbox _author. Пока справляюсь только с простыми sql запросами... Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А зачем вам 2 разные таблицы. ведь вам приходится каждое сообщение дублировать в inbox того кому пишут и outbox того кто пишет. лучше держать одну таблицу и в ней поля отправителя и получателя

Comment: для того что бы если я очистил у себя диалог с пользователем, то у него что бы не стёрлись сообщения которые я ему отправлял

Comment: для диалогов стоит подумать об использовании отдельной таблицы room или поля room_id, упростит задачу при увеличении базы

Comment: @Den Ну это решается просто полем в котором помечается, что запись удалена. Можно двумя битами, для отправителя и получателя, можно еще как. Но хранить две копии точно не зачем

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Вредные советы

Когда есть одинаковые данные, но их нужно показывать разным пользователям или разделить по уровням доступа - создавайте для каждого уровня доступа/пользователя таблицы и пишите данные туда. Сколько уровней доступа/пользователей - столько и таблиц! **Все просто** :)

---

...а потом мучайтесь с запросами и другими вопросами..А теперь по делу...

### Введение в проблему

Думаете будут только конфликты? Оставьте такую архитектуру...немного подождите и будет нарушение согласованности данных, излишнее дублирование приводящее к неграмотному использованию дискового пространства, а также проблемы производительности и построения запросов.

Ваша архитектура допускает излишнее дублирование данных, мало того, указанная архитектура, как Вы видите приводит лишь к усложнению процесса написания запросов и усложнению процесса ее поддержки.

В базах данных часто не используют для удаления данных метод прямого исключения записи из памяти, а просто ставят флаг, кому эта запись больше не видна и не может быть использована. Например, в вашем случае можно было бы создать таблицу **dialog_deleted_messages** с полями **message_id и user_id** которая определяет сообщения, которые не видны определенному пользователю.

Когда вы проектируете реляционную базу данных, знайте, что одинаковые данные должны хранится в одной таблице, а остальные таблицы должны на них ссылаться и лишь в исключительных случаях хранить агрегированное значение, чтобы не делать лишнюю работу.

Почитайте про нормализацию базы данных - это вам пригодится для дальнейшего проектирования баз данных.

---

### Примерная архитектура БД для диалогов

1. **Таблица для хранения общей информации по диалогу**.

   - id INT
   - name VARCHAR(50)
   - created TIMESTAMP
2. **Таблица для хранения сообщений диалога** - здесь будут храниться все сообщения привязанные к диалогу.

   - id INT
   - dialog_id INT
   - text TEXT
   - created TIMESTAMP
3. **Таблица участников диалога**

   - dialog_id INT
   - user_id INT
   - joined TIMESTAMP (указывает, когда участник присоединился к диалогу, чтобы не показывать сообщения, которые были до того, как он присоединился, возможно заменить данное поле на смещение по Id, чтобы это работало быстрее)
4. **Таблица скрытых (удаленных) сообщений**

   - message_id INT
   - user_id INT